# What is the best way to combine jquery ui draggable / droppable and do ajax in the background for better UI experience?

Tags: jquery, ajax, draggable, droppable

I want to create a very fast UI with the ability drag and drop pictures.  J[query droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) seems like what i want  but i don't want to have the user wait for all of the ajax to complete before a drag and drop is completed.  What is the right pattern for making it look like the change was completed and do the ajax in the background so it doesn't slow down the UI experience and only come back with an error if the ajax failed?  I seems to be writing a lot of hacky code and i would imagine there is a cleaner best practice around this.

My issue is keeping track of the ajax responses and what client changes were made that drove those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your drop/completed handlers you should fire an ajax request. As you most probably already know, ajax is asynchronous by default so it won't lock or cause any issues for your users.

Comment: I understand that but my question is more about keeping track of state on the front end when the ajax callback comes back

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies or HTML5 local storage to keep track of application state. Callbacks modify cookies or local storage. Firing your callback (or, preferably, changes to data model) could trigger a Javascript event that the UI controller code listens for.